# Why is Zinc reduced instead of Hydrogen, in the electrolysis of aqueous Zinc Sulfate, using Carbon electrodes?

Tags: electrolysis

In the electrolysis of aqueous zinc sulfate using carbon electrodes, why are zinc ions reduced at the cathode, instead of hydrogen ions? How does this relate to over potential?

It would mean a lot to me, if someone could provide a detailed answer.

Comment: Zinc ions are reduced because there are much more of them. Should hydrogen ions be equally abundant, we'd have hard time getting any Zn at all.